# My.settings is not null

Tags: vb.net

i start a new application and wen the form is load i need to check if my.settings.username key exits

well i know how to know if is empty or null how can i do to verify if the key exist?
For example what i need to change or add to this line
for example an else or some thing like that?
     on the line If String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.username)

This is my code

```
Private Sub trial_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim today As System.DateTime
    Dim answer As System.DateTime

    today = System.DateTime.Now


    Dim trialregister = Label2
    Dim username = TextBox1.Text



    Label2.Text = today
    Label6.Text = My.Settings.trialend

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.username) Then
        MsgBox("Email cannot be blank!", vbExclamation, "Media Mega Voip")
        TextBox1.Focus()


    End If
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.trialregister) Then
        today = System.DateTime.Now

        My.Settings.trialregister = today
        My.Settings.trialend = today.AddDays(30)
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.trialend) Then
        My.Settings.trialregister = today
        My.Settings.trialend = today.AddDays(30)
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If



    If My.Settings.trialregister = My.Settings.trialend Then
        Serials.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way you can check to see if a Setting Name is present:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If SettingPresent("username") Then
        Debug.Print("Setting `username` present.")
    Else
        Debug.Print("Setting `username` NOT present.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function SettingPresent(ByVal SettingName As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim x = My.Settings.Item(SettingName)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```